# NHibernate - Select records by server's date

Tags: c#, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

Im using NHibernate4 and Oracle 12.
NHibernate configured to use Oracle10gDialect.

First related code.

```
public class WorkOrder 
{
    ........
    public virtual DateTime CreationDate {get; set;}
    ........
}
```

CreationDate Mapped as:

```
Map(x => x.CreationDate)    
  .Column("CREATION_DATE")
  .CustomType("DateTime")
  .Access.Property()
  .Generated.Never()
  .CustomSqlType("DATE")
  .Not.Nullable();
```

Query samples:

```
var workOrders1 = session.Query<WorkOrders>()
       .Where(p => DateTime.Today.Date.Equals(p.CreationDate.Date))
       .ToList();

var workOrders2 = session.Query<WorkOrders>()
       .Where(p => p.CreationDate.Date == DateTime.Today.Date)
       .ToList();

    var workOrders3 = session.Query<WorkOrders>()
       .Where(p => p.CreationDate.Date.Equals(DateTime.Today.Date))
       .ToList();
```

All linq queries above converted to sql like this:

```
select workorders0_.CREATION_DATE  as CREATION11_ 
from   APPS.WORK_ORDERS workorders0_
where  TIMESTAMP '2016-04-16 00:00:00' /* :p0 */ = trunc(workorders0_.CREATION_DATE)
```

These queries uses client computers system time (and as a parameter), not servers system time. I always prefer to use server time. For oracle database i'm working on, i prefer "sysdate" because "CreationDate" field setted by by before insert trigger using "sysdate" function.

Can NHibernate use server's datetime directly? and parameter is not required. Like:

```
select workorders0_.CREATION_DATE  as CREATION11_
from   APPS.WORK_ORDERS workorders0_
where  trunc(sysdate) = trunc(workorders0_.CREATION_DATE)
```

As summary, "where" part must be changed from first one to second one. NHibernate version is v4.0.30319

```
where  TIMESTAMP '2016-04-16 00:00:00' /* :p0 */ = trunc(workorders0_.CREATION_DATE)
where  trunc(sysdate) = trunc(workorders0_.CREATION_DATE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to extend [linq-to-nhibernate](/questions/tagged/linq-to-nhibernate) for supporting this. (Even `DateTime.Now` is not translated to some SQL equivalent.)

The easiest way should be adding support for additional SQL function as [demonstrated by this blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/custom-linq-extensions-for-nhibernate), if your Oracle `sysdate` can be handled as a function. (With SQL Server, it is `sysdatetime()`, and it can be handled in linq2NH as a function.)

But unfortunately, there is a big limitation in current [linq-to-nhibernate](/questions/tagged/linq-to-nhibernate): only method call on entities or entity properties may get translated to SQL. Any other call will get evaluated at .Net run-time, as explained [here](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3386?focusedCommentId=27195&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-27195).

To overcome this, we have to add some dummy parameter to our function call. Here is what I have done in SQL-Server:

```sql
create function dbo.customGetDate (@dummy sql_variant = null)
returns datetime2 as
begin
    return sysdatetime()
end
```

```cs
using NHibernate.Linq;

...

public static class CustomLinqExtensions
{
    [LinqExtensionMethod("dbo.customGetDate")]
    public static DateTime GetSysDate(this object dummy)
    {
        // No need to implement it in .Net, unless you wish to call it
        // outside IQueryable context too.
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You would then be able to write:

```cs
var workOrders1 = session.Query<WorkOrders>()
   .Where(p => p.GetSysDate().Date == p.CreationDate.Date)
   .ToList();
```

If you want to avoid declaring a custom function in db, you should then extend linq2NH with a harder way, like adding your own "LinqToHqlGenerator" as in my [self-answer here](/a/36211132/1178314). But you will still have to call your extension on some entity, or entity properties.

This is ugly, but I do not find any better way.

Comment: Thank you vey much. But i'm getting An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in NHibernate.dll
Additional information: PartialEvalException (NotImplementedException ("The method or operation is not implemented."), PartialEvalException (NotImplementedException ("The method or operation is not implemented."), GetSysDate()).Date)
I searched for this method and it must works. I made some tests with different oracledialects nothing changed.

Comment: Doing now my own tests, and yes, its looks this extension attribute does not supports parameter less functions... Quite unfortunate. I can call any function having parameters, including user defined ones (including their schema in their name). So this can be workaround by adding a user defined function having a dummy parameter which call the parameter less function. I am still looking for better solution. It looks like it must be called on some mapped entity property. Quite a big limitation.

Comment: I have not found anything better. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much Frédéric. Your solution is running perfectly.There are other topics on this forum asking for exactly same issue, i will add comments referencing this one.

Comment: Well, I was even considering deleting my answer, as this is quite an unsatisfactory hack for me. But since it helps anyway, it will stay.